# SciChart WPF 50 EEG example not showing data on GUI

Tags: scichart

I have exported 50 EEG example from SciChart aplication to a standalone solution. 
When i start debug, lines are not drawn, but the code is running and generated data seems ok. 
I have not made any modifications the the example code.

[image: 50 EEG Example runtime]

Comment: Asked & answered here https://www.scichart.com/questions/wpf/scichart-wpf-50-eeg-example-not-showing-data-on-gui

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SciChart Forums](https://www.scichart.com/questions/wpf/scichart-wpf-50-eeg-example-not-showing-data-on-gui), the chart being blank is likely related to trial licensing, which needs to be set.

> See [Licensing SciChart WPF](https://www.scichart.com/licensing-scichart-wpf/) for how to get a trial license key.
>
> See App.xaml.cs of any exported project to see where to set the license.

```
using System.Windows;
using SciChart.Examples.ExternalDependencies.Controls.ExceptionView;

namespace SciChartExport
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {

             InitializeComponent();

             // TODO: Put your SciChart License Key here if needed
             // SciChartSurface.SetRuntimeLicenseKey(@"{YOUR SCICHART WPF v6 LICENSE KEY}");
        }  
    }
}
```